# Getting Nokogiri to work with Delayed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, delayed-job

I am trying to get Nokogiri to behave when using it with delayed jobs but haven't been very successful so far.

Basically I am trying to run a parsing task in the background, but when the background worker hits my perform method, it fails in the following line:

```
HTML_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.mysite.com'))
```

The error message is:

> Nokogiri::HTML::Document#inspect failed with ArgumentError: Requires a Node, NodeSet or String argument, and cannot accept a Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.

This happens with both `Delayed::Jobs.enqueue` and `delay` methods.

If I try the line below in the console, I get the same error:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.mysite.com')).delay
```

It might be a silly oversight as I am fairly new to Ruby and Rails, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Nokogiri "Requires a Node, NodeSet or String argument", why not give it one?

Instead of:

```
HTML_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.mysite.com'))
```

try:

```
HTML_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.mysite.com').read)
```

That will cause IO to read the file handle created by `open` and pass Nokogiri the string content of the URL being read.

An alternate way to help debug the problem, which I don't think lies within Nokogiri, is to split your command up a bit:

```
body = open('http://www.mysite.com').read
HTML_page = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
```